# Can there be multiple instances of a dependency in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have mirrored some code from XLabs to get Network State Tracking on my device from here: [Xlabs INetwork Android Implementation](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/blob/master/src/Platform/XLabs.Platform.Droid/Services/Network.cs)

I've pretty much aligned it with coding standards here and changed some method names - everything is working fine, except for some reason on the android implementation i am unable to get my event handlers to respond, the same way they do on iOS.

**This is my Adaptation for Android:**

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(STM.Droid.DependencyInjection.Network))]
[assembly: UsesPermission("android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE")]
[assembly: UsesPermission("android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE")]
[assembly: UsesPermission("android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE")]
[assembly: UsesPermission("android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE")]
namespace Namespace.Droid
{
    [BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true)]
    [IntentFilter(new [] { Android.Net.ConnectivityManager.ConnectivityAction })]
    public class Network : BroadcastReceiver, INetwork
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Internets the connection status.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>NetworkStatus.</returns>
        public NetworkStatus GetConnectionStatus()
        {
            var status = NetworkStatus.NotReachable;

            using (var cm = (ConnectivityManager)Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.ConnectivityService))
            using (var ni = cm.ActiveNetworkInfo)
            {
                if (ni != null && ni.IsConnectedOrConnecting)
                {
                    var name = ni.TypeName.ToUpper();
                    if (name.Contains("WIFI"))
                    {
                        status = NetworkStatus.ReachableViaWiFiNetwork;
                    }
                    else if (name.Contains("MOBILE"))
                    {
                        status = NetworkStatus.ReachableViaCarrierDataNetwork;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        status = NetworkStatus.ReachableViaUnknownNetwork;
                    }
                }
            }

            return status;
        }

        private readonly object lockObject = new object();
        private EventHandler<NetworkStatus> _reachabilityChanged;
        public event EventHandler<NetworkStatus> ReachabilityChanged
        {
            add
            {
                lock (this.lockObject)
                {
                    this._reachabilityChanged += value;
                }
            }

            remove
            {
                lock (this.lockObject)
                {
                    this._reachabilityChanged -= value;
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Occurs when [reachability changed].
        /// </summary>
//      public event EventHandler<NetworkStatus> ReachabilityChanged;

        /// <summary>
        /// Determines whether the specified host is reachable.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="host">The host.</param>
        /// <param name="timeout">The timeout.</param>
        public Task<bool> IsReachableAsync(string host, TimeSpan timeout)
        {
            return Task.Run(
                () =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var address = InetAddress.GetByName(host);

                        return address != null; // && (address.IsReachable((int)timeout.TotalMilliseconds) || );
                    }
                    catch (UnknownHostException)
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                });
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Determines whether [is reachable by wifi] [the specified host].
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="host">The host.</param>
        /// <param name="timeout">The timeout.</param>
        public async Task<bool> IsReachableByWifiAsync(string host, TimeSpan timeout)
        {
            return GetConnectionStatus() == NetworkStatus.ReachableViaWiFiNetwork && await IsReachableAsync(host, timeout);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This gets called by OS when the <see cref="ConnectivityManager.ConnectivityAction"/> <see cref="Intent"/> fires.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="context">Context for the intent.</param>
        /// <param name="intent">Intent information.</param>
        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            // this is a workaround - which oddly enough forwards events the way i would expect it to.
            MessagingCenter.Send(this as INetwork, string.Empty, GetConnectionStatus());

            // THIS IS ALWAYS NULL!
            var handler = _reachabilityChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                var connectionStatus = this.GetConnectionStatus();
                handler(this, connectionStatus);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The error in question occurs in OnReceive.

While in debugging i do notice that the handlers are attached correctly on the PCL side - there will just be null on that _reachabilityChanged field oddly enough.

As debugging indicates i am apparently getting

**{md50e2cce2f1202796e628729fe0540389b.Network@b422684}**

on the droid OnReceive method for "this"

while on the PCL side i am getting

**{md50e2cce2f1202796e628729fe0540389b.Network@b562641}**

when calling DependencyService.Get

To me this looks like the reason the handler list is empty, is because i am subscribing my handler on another instance and therefore do not get any handlers when a different instance of Network calls OnReceive.

Is it even possible for Xamarin.Forms DependencyService to provide 2 or more instances of an instance? Because that would surprise me a lot...

UPDATE:

In case someone needs a workaround - this works as well:

```
public event EventHandler<NetworkStatus> ReachabilityChanged
        {
            add { MessagingCenter.Subscribe(value.Target, string.Empty, (INetwork d, NetworkStatus a) => value(d, a)); }
            remove { MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe<INetwork>(value.Target, string.Empty); }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

for new instance 
`_client = DependencyService.Get<YOUINTERFACE>(DependencyFetchTarget.NewInstance);`
by default `DependencyService` is keep single